# How does keeper of the shrine work?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I play keeper of the shrine. It states that it counts as two tributes for a dragon type monster. Would it then be able to special summon a red eyes b dragon from my hand?

Comment: Tribute summons are not Special summons, and nothing on the card suggests it could do anything different except count 2-for-1 for a Dragon-type.

Answer (score 1):

The first effect on **Keeper of the Shrine** allows you to summon a level 7 or higher dragon type monster by using only **Keeper of the Shrine** as a tribute.
Except in the case of **Victory Dragon** which requires **Keeper of the Shrine** and one more tribute.

The second allows you to special summon **Keeper of the Shrine** from either your hand or graveyard if a different Dragon type monster is sent to the Graveyard.
If the monster sent to the Graveyard is also a Normal type monster you can then additionally return 1 Dragon / Normal type monster from the Graveyard to your hand.

Generally special summoning doesn't require tributes, and **Keeper of the Shrine** will only allow you to special summon **Keeper of the Shrine**.

Comment: I'm deleting the comments here. Thanks for fixing the formatting; this is in line with [Stack Exchange standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/295232). Whether we can/should have exceptions here on Boardgames.SE can be discussed on our own [meta] if necessary.